# How to redirect pages with php extension in GRAV

Tags: php, redirect, grav

I created a new web site using Grav.
The old site has pages that had to be accessed using urls ending .php
The url /somefolder/somepage.php just gives me "File not found".
It does NOT lead me to the built-in Grav error page.

I disabled the error plugin of Grav so it does not get in the way.

How do I rewrite /somefolder/somepage.php to /somefolder/somepage
Also, how can I redirect **any 404 error** to the home page?
The error is handled by:

> /var/www/grav-admin/system/src/Grav/Common/Processors/PagesProcessor.php

```
if (!$page->routable()) {
            // If no page found, fire event
            $event = $this->container->fireEvent('onPageNotFound');

            if (isset($event->page)) {
                unset ($this->container['page']);
                $this->container['page'] = $event->page;
            } else {
                throw new \RuntimeException('Page Not Found', 404);
            }
        }
```

How can I replace the line "throw new \RuntimeException('Page Not Found', 404);" with an instruction to redirect to the home page?

The above error is only caught for urls **NOT** ending in .php
urls ending in .php are not handled by Grav, so I guess it's the web server handing those errors. The web server is nginx/1.11.9.
I tried adding the lines below to my nginx.conf but this did not resolve the problem.

```
error_page 404 = @foobar;

    location @foobar {
      rewrite  .*  / permanent;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would handle both of your problems on server-side.

> How do I rewrite /somefolder/somepage.php to /somefolder/somepage

I would do something like :

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  if (!-f $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^(.*)\.php$ $1.html permanent;
  }
}
```

Which mean : for every php file requested, remove the php and replace .php by .html.

> Also, how can I redirect any 404 error to the home page?

This problem may occur because of 2 common things :

- http header problem : you don't change the http header in your redirect here so you still serve a 404. Before checking if the location exists, the server searches for the http code status. Here, it remains 404.
- you may use `fastcgi_intercept_errors on;`

For that problem, I would use this piece of code :

```
server {
  ...
  index index.html index.php
  error_page 404 = @hpredirect;
  ...
  location @hpredirect {
    return 301 /;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: I didn't check this answer for correctness because Grave has a setting in the admin page that does this already. Someone in the Grav forum pointed me to that. But thanks for your answer anyway.